# Programar con Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

Quiero trabajar con eclipse neon, la última versión. Quiero hacer una aplicación de escritorio, para lo cuál necesito utilizar la herramienta **WindowBuilder**; pero no la encuentro. En versiones antiguas sí que existe. Según la documentación debo instalar una actualización, pero todo lo relacionado con *WindowBuilder* sólo está hasta la versión 4.5 y eclipse neon es la versión 4.6.

Answer (score 3):

El proyecto WindowsBuilder aún no tiene soporte oficial para Eclipse Neon, la última versión para la cual tiene soporte es Eclipse Mars. Esto es debido a que desde la versión 4.6 (Neon) se usa una nueva forma para construir plugins dentro del proyecto Eclipse ([Tycho](https://eclipse.org/tycho/))

De acuerdo al [foro](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1076619/) de Eclipse se ha venido trabajando en darle [soporte](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=481842) a Neon pero quienes mantenían el proyecto original ya no lo hacen por lo que no hay confirmación de cuándo podrá estar disponible de forma oficial. Sin embargo, [aquí](http://zaunerc.blogspot.com.co/2016/06/windowbuilder-p2-update-site-for.html) encuentra una manera de clonar el proyecto a su equipo y crearlo con Maven, pero la ejecución no está exenta de errores.